# How can I change the default build output directory in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, csproj, dotnet-cli

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. I want to define the output directory in my csproj. I don't know where to change in Visual Studio Code the destination folder to locate the dll files generated.

Comment: Is it not Right Click a project >> Properties>>Build>>Output>>Output Path like the normal visual studios?

Comment: No...it does not work this way in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode uses dotnet CLI and particularly for building the [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) command. Among others, it has the following option

```
-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
Directory in which to place the built binaries.
```

---

Assuming your building task is defined in `.vscode/tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "command": "dotnet build",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

You may add `-o` arg with the desired path. For example, change to:

```
...
"command": "dotnet build -o ${workspaceRoot}/bin/another_Debug/",
...
```

where `${workspaceFolder}` is one of VSCode [predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution):

> ${workspaceFolder} the path of the workspace folder that contains the tasks.json file

Comment: This command shows error like this MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
    Full command line: '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary -o /home/user/TestBuild/Sp ..Trial1/Trial1.csproj -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/dotnet.dll'
  Switches appended by response files:
Switch: -o /home/user/TestBuild/XXX

Answer (score 3):

If you want a consistent behavior from VSCode, VS and the dotnet CLI, I suggest editing the csproj file to set the output path by adding this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>..\custom-output-dir\</OutputPath>
  <!-- Remove this if you multi-target and need the created net*, netcoreapp* subdirs -->
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The second property prevents the SDK from adding a subdirectory for the target framework, which is needed for multi-targeting builds, but not so if you only target a single framework (= when you only have a `TargetFramework` property).

You can also use other properties when setting the path, for instance:

```
<OutputPath>..\custom-output-dir\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</OutputPath>
```

Assuming your project is `MyProj.csproj`, the output path would then be `..\cusotm-output-dir\Debug\MyProj\`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your task.json in VScode:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger.",
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

You can simply change the path of your binaries by changing this line: `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` to `"${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"`. Now all of your bianries will go to the folder bin.